# Не работает OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, opengl

Есть код

```
#include<Windows.h>    
#include<gl/GL.h>    
#include<gl/GLU.h>    
#include<gl/glut.h>   
#include<GL/freeglut.h>
#include<gl/freeglut_ext.h>
#include<GL/freeglut_std.h>
#include "pch.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(250, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Demo");
    Init_OpenGL();
    glutDisplayFunc(Display_Objects);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Перед тем, как это всё запустить, я добавил в свойствах проекта в VC++ в Включаемые Каталоги папку "include" в папке glut, и добавил в Каталоги Библиотек папку "lib" в папке glut. 
Но ничего не работает. Ошибки:

> error C3861: glutInit: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(12,25):
> error C2065: GLUT_DOUBLE: необъявленный идентификатор
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(12,39):
> error C2065: GLUT_RGB: необъявленный идентификатор
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(12,5):
> error C3861: glutInitDisplayMode: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(13,5):
> error C3861: glutInitWindowSize: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(14,5):
> error C3861: glutInitWindowPosition: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(15,5):
> error C3861: glutCreateWindow: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(16,5):
> error C3861: Init_OpenGL: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(17,21):
> error C2065: Display_Objects: необъявленный идентификатор
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(17,5):
> error C3861: glutDisplayFunc: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(18,21):
> error C2065: Reshape: необъявленный идентификатор
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(18,5):
> error C3861: glutReshapeFunc: идентификатор не найден
> 1>C:\Users\sukas\source\repos\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1\ProjectWinOpenGLTest1.cpp(19,5):
> error C3861: glutMainLoop: идентификатор не найден

Как сделать так, чтобы всё заработало?

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться, в каком файле находится объявление используемых функций, `glutInit` и т.д. А не подключать подряд все заголовки `<gl/glut.h>`, `<GL/freeglut.h>` Кроме того, `pch.h` обычно является именем прекомпилированного заголовочного файла. Странно, что не выдается предупреждение о том, что он идет не в начале файла. По идее, все до подключения прекомпилированного заголовочного файла должно игнорироваться.

Comment: @user7860670 А исправить-то это как?

Comment: Начните с *"Для начала нужно определиться, в каком файле находится объявление используемых функций"*

Comment: @user7860670 но мне нужно исправить ошибку, а не понять, где функции...

Comment: Чтобы исправить ошибку для начала надо понять, где функции...

Comment: @user7860670. Хорошо. Я поискал эти функции, но ничего не нашёл